# link clicked to change div text but needs original content back on clicking another link - js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I needed to change the text of a `Div` on a click, but I also need to get back the original content of the div by clicking another link.

How can I do it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#changeText').click(function() {
    $('#content').text("This is text changed using jquery");
  });
});
```

```css
#content {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="changeText">Click here to change text of div</a>
<a href="#" id="changeText2">Original Div content</a>
<div id="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create another event for `#changeText2`

One way is to store the orginal content of `#content` to a variable. When you want to revert the text, you can use the variable.

```js
var orginalText = ""; /* Variable to store the original content */

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#changeText').click(function(){
         orginalText = $('#content').html(); /* store the original content to the variable */
         $('#content').html("This is text changed using jquery");
    });

    $('#changeText2').click(function(){
         if ( orginalText != "" ) $('#content').html(orginalText); /* use the variable to revert the contentn */
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="changeText">Click here to change text of div</a>
<a href="#" id="changeText2">Original Div content</a>
<div id="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
```

---

Without Variable. Using `.data()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#changeText').click(function() {
    $('#content').data("orginal-content", $('#content').html());
    $('#content').html("This is text changed using jquery");
  });

  $('#changeText2').click(function() {
    $('#content').html($('#content').data("orginal-content"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="changeText">Click here to change text of div</a>
<a href="#" id="changeText2">Original Div content</a>
<div id="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
```

Comment: so you mean i have to add all content in it again, i just cant go back as it is to original div condition ?

Comment: please see the image -  https://www.dropbox.com/s/pd0axwgwtmihfsp/Screenshot%202018-02-13%2008.34.51.png?dl=0  ,  its giving error on variable `orginalText`

Comment: You have to declare the `orginalText` as global variable. Right now you are declaring it inside the function. There should be no `var` inside the function.

Comment: i am inside angular, ionic basically and it is showing me this error, wonering how to get rid of this

Comment: I added another example without using a variable. It using a `.data()`